# Compiler warns about unused code for private functions that are actually used

Tags: rust

I started grouping code for one of my projects into module files. I encountered a lot of warnings about unused code for functions in those modules, but the functions are actually used (privately within the module).

An example from [my project](https://github.com/kodecheck/kodecheck/blob/master/lib-spellcheck/src/spellcheck/corrections.rs#L46):

```
// ...

// Line 46:

fn calc_p(word: &str, dict: &Dictionary) -> f32
{
    if !dict.contains_key(word) {
        return 0.0;
    }

    let total: u32 = dict.values().sum();
    dict[word] as f32 / total as f32
}

...
```

But [at line 13 in the same file](https://github.com/kodecheck/kodecheck/blob/master/lib-spellcheck/src/spellcheck/corrections.rs#L13), same module the function is clearly used:

```
// ...

pub fn suggest_corrections(to_be_corrected: &str, dict: &Dictionary) -> Vec<(f32, String)>
{
    let candidates = create_candidates(to_be_corrected, dict);

    let mut weighted_candidates = candidates
        .into_iter()
        .map(|w| (calc_p(&w, dict), w)) // Line 13 - calc_p used here
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    weighted_candidates.sort_by(|a, b| b.partial_cmp(a).unwrap());

    weighted_candidates
}

// ...
```

Yet I get the compiler warning:

```
warning: function is never used: `calc_p`, #[warn(dead_code)] on by default
  --> src/spellcheck/corrections.rs:46:1
   |
46 |   fn calc_p(word: &str, dict: &Dictionary) -> f32
   |  _^ starting here...
47 | | {
48 | |     if !dict.contains_key(word) {
49 | |         return 0.0;
50 | |     }
51 | |
52 | |     let total: u32 = dict.values().sum();
53 | |     dict[word] as f32 / total as f32
54 | | }
   | |_^ ...ending here
```

I thought maybe it's because the module `corrections` is not public, but I also [marked the module as public](https://github.com/kodecheck/kodecheck/blob/master/lib-spellcheck/src/spellcheck/mod.rs) and still get the same warning.

I tried to reproduce the behaviour using [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=91e73fbec7c7e28337ff8279e112e873&version=stable&backtrace=0), but if the module is defined in the same file it seems to work. The warnings also happen for me during [a TravisCI build](https://travis-ci.org/kodecheck/kodecheck/jobs/212329539).

Why is the function marked as unused although it's actually used in the same file in the same module?

I'm using Rust 1.15 / 1.16.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is the function marked as unused although it's actually used in the same file in the same module?

Because unused code is a transitive calculation, and the code that calls that function cannot be called from outside the crate. The compiler is correct here.

---

The first error I see is:

```
warning: static item is never used: `ALPHABET`, #[warn(dead_code)] on by default
 --> src/spellcheck/edits.rs:3:1
```

That's defined as:

**src/spellcheck/edits.rs**

```
static ALPHABET : &'static str = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

So it's not public, and can only be used from inside the module.

It's called from `replaces` and `inserts`. Both of those are used from `edits1`, a public function. Is the module containing it (`edits`) public?

**src/spellcheck/mod.rs**

```
mod edits;
pub mod corrections;
pub mod dictionary;
```

Nope, it is not. So where is `edits1` called from? `kodecheck_spellcheck::spellcheck::corrections::create_candidates`, a non-public function. This is called by `suggest_corrections`, a public function, inside the public module `corrections`.

Let's look up the tree...

**src/lib-spellcheck.rs**

```
// @FIXME do we really need this here or move to sub-modules?
#[macro_use]
extern crate nom;
extern crate regex;

mod spellcheck;
```

Ah. For whatever reason, you've decided to introduce a completely nested private module `spellcheck` inside the crate (which is why the full path earlier is `kodecheck_spellcheck::spellcheck::corrections::create_candidates`).

From this, we can see that `kodecheck_spellcheck::spellcheck` **cannot be accessed from outside the crate**; it's not `pub`.

---

Let's create an example that uses the crate. This the the best way to see if it's true and would have been easy for you to test yourself:

**examples/foo.rs**

```
extern crate kodecheck_spellcheck;

fn main() {
    kodecheck_spellcheck::spellcheck::corrections::create_candidates();
}
```

Compiling this has the error:

```
error: module `spellcheck` is private
 --> examples/foo.rs:4:5
  |
4 |     kodecheck_spellcheck::spellcheck::corrections::create_candidates();
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

We could also create a [MCVE](/help/mcve):

```
mod spellcheck {
    mod edits {
        static ALPHABET: &'static str = "";

        pub fn edits1() {
            println!("{}", ALPHABET);
        }
    }

    pub mod corrections {
        pub fn create_candidates() {
            ::spellcheck::edits::edits1();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Note that this differs from your example because `main` is empty. Your library crate doesn't have a `main`method that calls anything. You could also explicitly specify that it's a library crate, but this is less well-known:

```
#![crate_type="lib"]

mod spellcheck {
    mod edits {
        static ALPHABET: &'static str = "";

        pub fn edits1() {
            println!("{}", ALPHABET);
        }
    }

    pub mod corrections {
        pub fn create_candidates() {
            ::spellcheck::edits::edits1();
        }
    }
}
```

---

Because there's a private module where all the code is, *nothing* outside this crate can call anything *inside* the crate. Therefore every method is unreachable.

To fix it, I'd suggest combining **src/spellcheck/mod.rs** into **src/lib-spellcheck.rs**. You could also just make the module public, but I see no reason to have the extra module.

I also see no reason to rename **src/lib.rs** to **src/lib-spellcheck.rs**; it's far more idiomatic to just leave it **lib.rs**.

---

Additionally, you should go ahead and become comfortable with Rust style. Braces go on the same line as the signature:

```
fn calc_p(word: &str, dict: &Dictionary) -> f32 {
    // ...
```

Tools like [rustfmt](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt) will help you apply the proper style.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yeah, I didn't think about crate-level visibility. I agree the nested submodule is weird, that should be removed and I move the modules one level up. As a beginner in Rust I have to say the module system is one of the weaker aspects of the language and gave me a bit of trouble, but I hope I can get the hang out of it some time.

Comment: Couldn't the warning message be clearer? I'm running into something similar, and a warning that says "function is never used" when the function is actually used seems needlessly confusing. This is a surprising choice given that Rust compiler diagnostics seem to be generally very high-quality and helpful otherwise.

Comment: Ah actually, your more recent answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51636336 seems to be relevant, as "if your library exports `fn a()` and `fn b()` and one binary uses `a` and another binary uses `b`, then no compilation of the library or either binary would ever see the whole picture" is exactly what's going on in my case.