# How can I get the compiler to warn me of unused code that is marked pub?

Tags: rust, compiler-warnings

Rust warns for unused private items:

```
warning: function is never used: `hmm`
   --> src/example.rs:357:1
    |
357 | fn hmm() {
    | ^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: #[warn(dead_code)] on by default
```

I have some code marked `pub` that I know is not being used. How can I get the compiler to warn me of this?

This is in the context of a library and a series of binaries, all in the same workspace. The library is only used by those binaries; the library isn't being consumed by anybody else and I'm not going to upload to crates.io, so I have full knowledge of the code that's being used.

Comment: We could use more details. Is the project a library or a binary?

Comment: Could you clarify how you know it is not used? Normally, anything `pub` can be used by any downstream user.

Comment: Added more context via an edit. I have single Cargo.toml that builds a `lib` and a series of `bin`s.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot enable anything to do this. By definition, if something is public outside of your crate, it may be used by the crates that import your crate; there's no way for the compiler to actually tell. This is part of having a *public API*. Removing something from the public API is a breaking change.

If you have an item that's not exported from your crate, the fact that it's `pub` won't matter:

```
mod foo {
    pub fn bar() {}
}

fn main() {}
```

```
warning: function is never used: `bar`
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     pub fn bar() {}
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(dead_code)] on by default
```

Instead, *don't mark things as public* to start with. Instead, either leave off `pub` entirely or use a visibility modifier like `pub(crate)`. Binary crates should basically have no items marked for export from the crate.

---

In your specific case of a workspace, there's never a time when a single compiler invocation knows "everything". For example, if your library exports `fn a()` and `fn b()` and one binary uses `a` and another binary uses `b`, then no compilation of the library or either binary would ever see the whole picture. The "best" case would be getting tons of false positives.

In similar situations, I've resorted to removing *everything* public from the API and compiling to see the errors / used functions.

A tool called [warnalyzer](https://github.com/est31/warnalyzer) **might** help in this case. It uses some unstable compiler features to save files from intermediate compiler invocations, then aggregates them to identify unused code. It has a number of false positives at the moment, but it might be useful as a guide.

Comment: *In similar situations, I've resorted to removing everything public from the API and compiling to see the errors / used functions.* Dirty. Perfectly worked.

Answer (score 4):

Somewhat related: the [rust issue #74970](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/74970) asks that `pub` is treated as `pub(crate)` in bin crates so that diagnostics like unused code work even if the more fine-grained `pub(...)` specifiers are not used.